# Analyzing MODIS MCD12Q1 level 3 data in ENVI?

Tags: envi, modis

How can i see the classes of the product MODIS MCD12Q1 and analyze them in ENVI exelis? Seadas open them but ENVI not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the MDC12Q1 product consists of several subdatasets (layers), you are most likely interested in the first five where each represents a different classification system.

1. IGBP
2. UMD
3. LAI/fPAR
4. NPP/BGC
5. PFT

You will need to decide on the classification scheme you want to use and then select the appropriate layer to open. Each layer is 8-bit unsigned and has values ranging from 0 to 254.

A table describing which value represents which class can be found in the [official MCD12Q1 documentation](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/modis_products_table/mcd12q1)

Comment: I have already done this. I have chosen the IGBP layer but it still doesn't open. To be precise, envi coudn't recognise the georeference of hdf data so I have used the modis conversion toolkit in order to georeference them. This toolkit converted them to hdr and dat format but classes don't open in envi. I have tried Modis tool too but it didn't work. What else could i do?

Comment: You could always use GDAL to [warp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) a specific subdataset to a new SRS - eg. WGS84: `gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"`. You can get the full name of the subdataset for IGBP with `gdalinfo`. Or use a GIS software than can open .hdf files (e.g. QGIS) and reproject the required data from there.